# Retrieving remaining transactions from Bing Web Search API

Tags: c#, azure, bing-api

I'm working on a Windows Form that uses Bing Web Search API and I would like to display the remaining transactions I have left for the month. What would be the best way to do this? Should I use a WebRequest to do this, and if so how?

[Here is a picture of the Bing Transaction number I'm trying to get and display on my windows form project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKPgW.png)

Answer (score 1):

As I know, there is no such API. You can view the remaining transaction from the Account page from Marketplace. Sign in and click  "My Account", then choose "My Data". You will see all data you subscribed and how much quota it remains.